# Where is data attribute's value placed when applied to $(document)?

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

```
$( document ).data( 'foo', 'bar' );
```

Is there a DOM element that gets a `data` attribute

```
data-foo="bar"`
```

Or is the value `bar` stored internally by jQuery?

Comment: _"Or is the value bar stored internally by jQuery?"_ This.

Comment: And why applied data attribute to $(document) ?

Comment: @j08691 just what was afraid of... (btw... your's an answer not a comment)

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant some other people code I inherited...

Comment: I didn't think it had enough substance to qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This demo may shed some light. Please view the console output.

```js
$(document).data({'test1':'just a string','test2': [1,3,76,45],'test3':1000});
console.log( $(document).data() )
console.log( $(document)[0] );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```